# Not able to avoid the last character input when using the dojo keypress event

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to call a dojo on keypress event. What I want to achieve is that as soon as I encounter a '%', I want to start reading the subsequent characters and as soon as I encounter'?', I want to sub-string the text and replace the whole text in the box with the sub-stringed text.

While I am able to substring the text and everything, the issue that I am facing is the '?' which appears after the sub-stringed text.

ie when '?' is pressed, the string is substringged and the required text is substituted in the box. However, the text is accompanied by '?', which i do not want.

E.g.
I enter **11111%B3333555533335555?**, so i want tht whole text to be replaced by **3333555533335555**, however, in my case it is ending with **3333555533335555?**
I am using the following code for calling the event:

```
require(["dojo/keys", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
            function(keys, dom, on){
        on(dom.byId(abc), "keypress", function(evt){
//substring the code here and set the value back
});
});
```

Moreover, **keyup** event is not working for me. Don't know if that would have solved the problem, but its not functioning. Tried in Firefox and IE.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "**keyup** is not working for me" so I can help address that in my answer?

Comment: use keydown to filter/cancel keys, keypress and keyup are too late... `evt.preventDefault()` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you've tried the "keyup" event and it "didn't work", i would suggest looking in to this event. The [keyup event](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/key_events/) is thrown when the key is already released, which would be the perfect time to replace the input (input.set("value", value) with the modified value.

Please explain what went wrong while using keyup.
I've created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ey7jq069/3/) which makes use of the keyup event.

```
require(["dojo/keys", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!", "dijit/form/TextBox"],
        function(keys, dom, on, domready, tb){
    var textbox = dom.byId("abc");
    on(textbox, "keyup", function(evt){
        //substring the code here and set the value back
        console.log(evt.target.value);
        if (evt.target.value.indexOf("?") > -1){
            evt.target.value = evt.target.value.substring(0, evt.target.value.indexOf("?"));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The keypress event is fired after the letter has been inserted in your textbox (or whatever you're using to collect input), and thus you are getting the question mark in your string. So I would modify your code like so:

```
require(["dojo/keys", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
            function(keys, dom, on){
        on(dom.byId(abc), "keypress", function(evt){
            //substring the code here and set the value back
            evt.target.value = evt.target.value.slice(evt.target.value.indexOf("%") + 1, -1);
        });
});
```